# Styling a button inside a table different is behaving differently in chrome vs firefox.

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using below mentioned code to make a button to fill all the cell in a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn">button</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn{
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
}

table{
    min-height:500px;
}
```

But the behavior is different in chrome and firefox

Fiddle link: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/ujPEg/)

Thanks for your help

Comment: min-height is defined for tables in Firefox. change it to height. If the content is more table will expand anyways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521442/min-height-for-a-table-in-firefox-not-working

Comment: @Ankur thank you for the answer, but I still have the same problem, the button doesn't fill the cell, I want the button to fill the cell. Also I find useful your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here the working example for your specified problem
http://jsfiddle.net/suriyag/PsEg8/1/
just remove the height and it works fine

```
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I changed min-height to height, as @Ankur Aggarwal told me.

Second I added JQuery

Thrid I added this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").outerHeight($(".btn").parent().outerHeight());
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/ujPEg/2/